# Get the list of voicemail and voicemail information from Voicemail Server- Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, sip, voip, voicemail

I have to implement getting the list of voicemail(if there are any) from Voicemail Server and put them in a tableView. It's just like a notification or a header.

Ex: "You have 3/3 voicemail from 5203".

So I would like to know how to do it and other things that I have to research. Also, how long will it take to implement this?

Comment: You can't.  You didn't specify.  NaN.

Comment: Avi  What should I specify?